# Slow random number generation python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

I've made a small project to display the results of a certain number of dice thrown a certain number of times based on user input. It works fine but especially when I input large values the program takes forever to generate the data. My computer is fairly high end so it's not a hardware problem.

```
import random
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nd = int(input("Insert number of dice: ")) 
nt = int(input("Insert number of throws: "))
print(nd, " dice thrown ", nt, " times")
print("Generating sums, please hold....")
c = 1
i = 1
sum = 0
sums = []
while nt >= i :
    while nd >= c:
        g = random.randint(1, 6)
        sum = sum + g
        c += 1
    sums.append(sum)
    i = i+1
    c=1
    sum = 0
    print("Throw ", i, " of ", nt)
sums.sort()
max = max(sums)
min = min(sums)
print("||Maximum result: ", max, " ||Minimum result: ", min)

print("Now ordering results")

f = Counter(sums)
x = list(f.values())
y = list(f.keys())

print("Rappresenting results")

plt.plot(y, x)
plt.xlabel("Risultati")
plt.ylabel("Frequenza")
plt.title("Distribuzione delle somme")
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Python runs in 1 thread by default so if you use very large number it will take longer, you can try to improve its performance by parallelizing the process so it can take advantage of multi-core architecture. So for example if you are throwing 6 dice 1000 times and have a 6 core machine you could do the calculations for each dice in a different process and then sum the results at the end.

Comment: Have you attempted to profile your code to determine exactly where the bottleneck lies?